# replacing an url in a browser automatically with python

Tags: python, url, browser

when I enter the youtube URL in my browser I want the URL to automatically change and visit a different website (invidio.us). Can someone provide any pointers as to how to achieve this with Python?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can solve this in python. You will need a browser plugin for this one, and the add-ons aren't written in python.
Try JavaScript.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).